# "The input was not valid" .NET Core Web API with Razor Pages

Tags: jquery, asp.net, post, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Anyone can help please, when i use post method in postman i only get "The input was not valid". Please help, i was spend too much time on this!!!

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(M05PurchaseAgreement item)
{
    _context.M05PurchaseAgreement.Add(item);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtRoute("GetTodo", new { agreementNo = item.AgreementNo }, item);
}
```

Model:

```
public class M05PurchaseAgreement
{
    [Key]
    public string AgreementNo { set; get; }
    public string Status { set; get; }
    public string OrderStatus { set; get; }
    public string AccountStatus { set; get; }
    public string StockID { set; get; }
    public string RegistrationNo { set; get; }
    public string Revision { set; get; }
    public string CalendarPeriod     { set; get; }
    public string PurchaseType { set; get; }
    public DateTime PurchaseDate { set; get; }
    public string PurchaseSalesman { set; get; }
    public decimal PurchasePrice { set; get; }
    public string TaxMethod { set; get; }
    public string PurchaseInvoice { set; get; }
    public string EntryStaff { set; get; }
    public DateTime EntryDate { set; get; }
    public string LastEditStaff { set; get; }
    public DateTime LastEditDate { set; get; }
    public string Notes { set; get; }
    public string BranchCode { set; get; }
    public string Location { set; get; }
}
```

**Edit - Im using Jquery**

Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://localhost:44328/api/m05purchaseagreement',
    accepts: 'application/json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(item),
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(item));
    },
    success: function (result) {
        $('#agreementNo').val('');
    }
});
```

Comment: This should help: [Binding Complex Objects](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding#binding-complex-objects).

Comment: But my Model and Controller are inside the WebApi

Comment: Could you show your postman image and the `item` value of ajax?Besides, make sure that the three DateTime fields' values are correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `[ApiController]`,model validation errors automatically trigger an HTTP 400 response.
You could disable the default behavior by setting `SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter` property to true.See the doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2#annotation-with-apicontroller-attribute).

In Postman,I post model data with raw json like below.

[image]

In controller, use `[FromBody]`

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody] M05PurchaseAgreement item)
```

And in view, you need to pass json data, your item is similar to

```
var item = { "Status": "active", "OrderStatus": "active" };
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution, but still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this and nothing worked for me until I realised I had selected 'text' instead of 'JSON' in Postman, see this image:

[image]

After I changed this I got the correct results.